# Django. Comparing the model fields before saving for the admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm new to Django and I have a question (Yes, yes, I was looking for and did't find ...).
There are two models:

```
class CounterDetail(models.Model):
counter = models.ForeignKey(Counter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
date_placing = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=False, null=False)
verifying_period_mounts = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
```

and

```
class Detail(models.Model):
counterdetail = models.ForeignKey(CounterDetail, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
date_last_verification = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=False, null=False)
date_obxoda = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=False, null=False)
```

How to implement the check when adding an entry to the second model through the admin panel: 
field `date_obxoda = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=False, null=False)`more then date_placing = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=False, null=False) from another model.

I'm looking for a method (preferably as an overridden save () method in the model) when adding records via the admin panel, to verify that the date from the second model (with a foreign key) is greater than the first.

Please give an example, thank you.

Comment: Django provide a [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/), so you don't need Foreign key referencing to each other in both model. Also could you please explain a bit more what you want to do ?

Comment: Hah.) They do not refer to each other. The first model refers to a completely different table, but that's another story ...I added a paragraph with a more detailed description.

Comment: ohh.. my bad, I didn't notice. well posted an answer, check it.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23361057, https://stackoverflow.com/q/25647498

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can override Detail model save method like

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Detail, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.date_obxoda > self.counterdetail.date_placing :
        #do_something
```

let me know if this help

Comment: Thank you friend. But there was a new question) How to generate an error so that in the administrator of the panel the field turned red. I was able to only display the ValidationError to the full screen)

Comment: override the `clean()' method just like you did to `save()` with same code. `def clean(self):
    if self.date_obxoda > self.counterdetail.date_placing :
        #do_something
        return self.cleaned_data`

Comment: Bro, I really appreciate it.

Comment: happy to help you bro ;)